# Error "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" appears, but why?

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I want to create a socket communication, but there appears an error if i run following script: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

```
import socket
import time

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.169"
UDP_PORT = 5005
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # INTERNET
socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

while True:
    v = input("Message:      ")
    MESSAGE = str(v)
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/snd.py", line 12, in <module>
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE,(UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: As the error describes, you cannot send a `str`, only a `bytes`.  Try `MESSAGE = v.encode('ascii')` or `MESSAGE = v.encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 0):

Socket requires you to pass a bytes-like object as an input, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html). As input always returns a string, you just have to encode it to get a bytes-like object from it. So just try something like

```py
...
while True:
    v = input("Message:      ")
    sock.sendto(v.encode(), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
...
```